# Make RAM size free for .NET application

Tags: c#, .net, ram

I have created some grid images like booklet pages on a WPF form. When I run my application the system RAM memory size is 1.02 GB (includes all other running  applications). When I turn each page RAM size increases by some kb. Finally when I turn more than 150 pages I get an Out Of Memory exception. I understand the exception is caused because there is no space in RAM to open new pages on my application and I tried the following:

```
     1. BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
        image.Dispose();
        image = null;


     2. Gc.Collect();



    3.[DllImport("psapi.dll")]
    public static extern bool EmptyWorkingSet(IntPtr hProcess);

public FreeMem(string programName){

      EmptyWorkingSet(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle);
      foreach(Process process in Process.GetProcesses(programName))
      {
            try
            {
                EmptyWorkingSet(process.Handle);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                ...
            }
      } 
}
```

But I couldn't solve my problem. Can anyone make me clear and solve this?

Comment: This is the kind of problem you resolve by debugging it, getting it into the high usage state, then breaking into the debugger and finding out what types of objects you have a large number of lurking around and what objects are keeping them alive. It's not possible to diagnose from your question because you're not showing us the code that causes the leak - you're just showing us your attempts to mop the floor. Without fixing the leak, mopping the floor does nothing.

Comment: Use any memory profiler for .Net to see where memory is used. Than figure out what object that you think are freed are still there... Profit.

Comment: good try man.i am also looking for the same.

Comment: you may try windbg to find out what is leaking; also, you may use JustTrace which is easier to use (http://www.telerik.com/products/memory-performance-profiler.aspx).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever @ Alexei  check my question now, i have edited.

Comment: No amount of garbage collecting is going to save you from keeping references to things you no longer need.

Comment: @daryal you have sent nice tutorial but i will happy if u tell how to do this by c# coding.

Comment: @manivasagam these are not tutorials; you need to find out what is leaking before fixing the code.

Comment: @manivasagam: compile the application as AnyCpu (x64) and you will solve the issue. I cannot post the comments as an answer.

Comment: @SoMoS thanks for your reply! my application should work fine also in x32 so i need to solve this fix using c# code.