# Outofmemory exception when do bitmapimage dispose

Tags: c#, out-of-memory

I have created `WPF` windows application for display more images using grid. My below code getting `OutOfMemory Exception` when I run my `application.exe`.

```
byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
File.Delete(path);
if (buffer == null)
   return null;
using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
{             
   BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
   bi.BeginInit();
   bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;

   bi.StreamSource = mStream;
   bi.EndInit();              
   bitmap = bi;
   bitmap.Freeze();
   mStream.Close();
   mStream.Dispose();
}
```

I found some solution from stackoverflow and changed my coding as following below,

```
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
{
    image.BeginInit();
    // image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.n;
    image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    image.UriSource = new Uri(path);
    image.EndInit();
    File.Delete(path);
    bitmap = image;
    image.UriSource = null;
    image = null;
}
```

But this code getting exception as that `image used by another process` or `cant open from locked file`.

I am totally confused why my application often caused by OutOfMemory or `used by another process` exception?

Comment: you can look at the bellow link for improving ram perfomance http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5a13a184-ef47-423a-89ed-7ca1b8a0aaf8/build-your-own-memory-optimizer-with-c?forum=netfxnetcom

Comment: You can also look at your post and answer to the question - "is my post well formatted? Would I like to read such posts from other people?"

Comment: @KVK even i tried that link code.its reducing RAM size fine but even  though getting same exception often.

Comment: Your code does not make sense to me. You are initializing a new `BitmapImage` object and then set it to `null`. Why? Are you trying to do a `using(BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage()) { ... }` ?

Comment: what did you mean by `I have created WPF windows application for display more images` ? how many? how big? what do you do with this images?

Comment: @Serv yes. actually i wanna dispose BitmapImage object so i assigned as null.

Comment: @WiiMaxx please look at my last post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24424466/make-ram-size-free-for-net-application. this should make you clear

Comment: The sane way to interpret this exception is that your are, you know, *out of memory*.  Not hard to do with bitmaps.  You ought to review the way you are using these bitmaps to look for a workaround.  The fix is otherwise trivial, just change the Platform target setting on your EXE project and allow your program to run in 64-bit mode.

Comment: @HansPassant ok but if i change it into 64-bit means will it works in 32-bit system???

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/12/dont-be-afraid-to-use-the-science/

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the comments, you are doing something wrong. You are initializing an obejct ob type `BitmapImage` and instantly declare it as null. So everything you have declared beforehand has gone down the crapper.

you should leverage the `using()` statements functionality here. If the code leaves this statement the GarbageCollector will automatically take over and dispose everything for you:

```
using(BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage())
{
    image.BeginInit();
    // image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.n;
    image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    image.UriSource = new Uri(path);
    image.EndInit();
    bitmap = image.Clone();
}
```

Comment: Yes, Instead of this Block(using(BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage()){...}) only I used my code which is already in question. Even if i use above code, am getting the same error.

Comment: No you did not. You posted 2 totally different pieces of code and the second one will never work. This means your error is most likely somewhere else.

Comment: @Serv i would suggest to add a `.Clone()` like `bitmap = image.Clone();`